# Find full filename given only partial filename

Tags: vba, excel, directory, filenames

I know the directory in which a file is located.

I know that this file will always begin with a word - let's say "David"

I know that there is only one file in this directory whose name begin's with "David"

How can I find the entire file's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   myFolder = "C:\SO"
   myPrefix = "David"
   myFileName = Dir(myFolder & "\" & myPrefix & "*")
   Debug.Print myFileName
```

Comment: Beautiful; I'll be accepting this an my answer after the time restraint has passed. Thanks